# What does var i$0 mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at a javascript file someone else wrote, and I see a loop that does this:

```
for (var i$0 = 0; i$0 < strings.length; ++i$0)
{
  var id$1 = strings[i$0][0];
  var data = strings[i$0][1];
  // ... blah
}
```

Since I am not super familiar with every feature javascript has to offer, what do `i$0` and `id$1` mean? Do they create a variable name based on input/command line parameters or do they do something else entirely?

Comment: the are just variable names

Comment: `$` is a valid character in variable names.

Comment: MDN: [Identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier) -- "identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters (or "$" or "_"), and may not start with a digit."

Comment: same thing as `$` in jQuery or $ and $$ in chrome's console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ is a valid character in a variable name. So they are normal variables.

By convention they are most used to refer to a jQuery object as this library's functions traditionally use $('something'). So it's natural that a jQuery object be assigned to:

```
var $button = $('#btn');
```

and because jQuery it's a very popular library, some people discourage it's use otherwise so not to confuse with it.

But you are free to use them as you see fit.